# Getting iso from mirrors

Tags: boot, iso, mirrors

How do I download the ISO file for a Linux distro from a mirror site? When I open mirrors, it shows a directory with multiple files. What exactly are they?

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually asking, but downloading an Ubuntu ISO from a local mirror is not hard; you go to [Official CD Mirrors for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors), pick your mirror, open it, choose your release, and download the desired ISO image.  For example, `http://ubuntu.mirrors.telekom.ro/ubuntureleases/18.04/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mirror sites](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/mirror/list.html) don't just hold one file, but many.  They're a convenience to users, so they can get Ubuntu without delays caused by slow data lines, or delays caused by a mob of users all downloading from the same site at the same time.

The public directory you are pointed in [an authorized mirror](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors), such as http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/releases/ may have many different distros for Ubuntu, with multiple release numbers, as well as multiple [flavors](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) which use different [desktop environments](https://www.lifewire.com/best-linux-desktop-environments-4120912), as well as a distro with none at all, the [server distro](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/difference-ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-server/). Distros almost end in .ISO, because they are an ['image'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) of an entire DVD or CD in one file. Start by picking the version you want, e.g., [http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu-releases/16.04.4/](http://mirror.vutbr.cz/ubuntu/releases/16.04.4/) and then you will see multiple files, including ISOs.

That directory also has [checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum), text files containing a hexadecimal string (like 0123456789ABCDEF), made by other open source programs. When you run a [checksum app](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and point it at the distro you just downloaded, the checksum app gives you a hexadecimal string you compare with the contents of the checksum for the distro.

If they match, then your ISO file arrived intact; if they don't, you need to redownload the ISO because it was corrupted in transit, and installing from it will just waste your time.

Comment: But I am unable to get the iso from mirrors. Like I want to download damn small linux's iso, there are so many files. How to find iso in them?

Comment: Damn Small Linux is not an Ubuntu release so is not supported here. http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/download.html lists the DSL mirrors; for other non-Ubuntu distros, search for them at http://distrowatch.org/ or with Ye Olde Google.

Comment: And, if you find an answer here solves your issue, please click on the checkmark at upper left to show it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

In, short, when see that huge list of files, all you have to do is click the one that includes ".iso" at the end.